# how to configure classified php scripts

Tags: php, scripting, ads

Got sfclassi script and I am really new to php and html. I have to set it up and change its layout a bit, but the problem is there is nothing in its index file just a little code

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

$configuration=ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('cfclient', 'prod', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

Can some one explain what is happening here and how can I change its layout when I don't even have any html file

Comment: What is "sfclassi script"? And what do you mean by "classified php scripts"?

Comment: sfclassi  is a php script that and many other are used to post ads on sites,like classified ads to sell some car or goods etc,

Comment: So you want to place ads on some sites? Sorry, but we have no idea what you are trying to do. So your question "what is going on here" is somewhat vague...

Comment: @darkcommet I assume that you bought the script from Code Canyon. Contact Code Canyon Support.

Comment: actually i didnt purchased the code,i am an intern,boss gave me this code and said make it like http://www.backpage.com/ and currently i have no idea but thanks for the quick response guys :)